# Populating more than one HTML statement from a Javascript change via Java

Tags: java, html, ajax, jsp

Im trying to populate two separate HTML objects when a change occurs in my webpage - one a dropdown list and one a form.

So in my JSP code I have this:

```
$('#uSystemList').change(function() {
    $.get("/live-application/systemById", {systemid: $("#uSystemList").val()}, displayChangedSystemResults, "html");
});

<script type="text/javascript">
function displayChangedSystemResults(html){
    $('#uList').empty();
    $('#uList').append(html);
}
</script>
```

And on the Java side I have this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/systemById", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getSystemById(@RequestParam("systemid") String systemid, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder refreshHtml = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String html = "";
        System system = service.getSystemById(systemid));
        for (Value value: inewsSystem.getValues()) {
            html = html + "<option value='" + value.getId() + "'> " + value.getName() + "</>";
            }
        } 
        refreshHtml.append(html );
        outputStream.write(refreshHtml.toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        outputStream.flush();
    }
}
```

So that populates my `uList` dropdown - but how do I tell it to populate something else as well (e.g. a form, but could be anything else as an example...). The `OutputStream` seems to only let me populate one object per change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it is not a bad idea to send two ajax request and have two spring controllers for handling each request. And subsequently, in JSP page you would need two javascript callback to populating different HTML sections.

Or, if you insist to make only one AJAX request; a workaround would be get the spring controller return a JSON, which contains the data for populating those two HTML sections. But with this approach it apparently requires a bit more javascript effort.

Answer (score 0):

This is Javascript not JSP :). You need to update:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function displayChangedSystemResults(html){
    $('#uList').empty();
    $('#uList').append(html);
    $('#someOtherElement').empty();
    $('#someOtherElement').append(html);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant from a JSP page. Ok, thanks for the post. But how does it know which part of the html is for the ulist and which is for someotherelement??